# Connect by clause output not coming as desired

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query against my `emp` table

```
SELECT  empno,mgr,ename,level
FROM emp
START WITH ename = 'KING'
CONNECT BY  PRIOR empno = mgr;
```

Desired output should be to show `ename` of the manager and without using a self join.

Comment: What raw data do you have, what output do you expect to see, and what do you actually get?

Comment: And, feel free to set up a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Raw data from emp table of oracle

Comment: output I get"EMPNO" "MGR" "ENAME" "LEVEL"
7839  "KING" 1
7566 7839 "JONES" 2
7788 7566 "SCOTT" 3
7876 7788 "ADAMS" 4
7902 7566 "FORD" 3
7369 7902 "SMITH" 4
7698 7839 "BLAKE" 2
7499 7698 "ALLEN" 3
7521 7698 "WARD" 3
7654 7698 "MARTIN" 3
7844 7698 "TURNER" 3
7900 7698 "JAMES" 3
7782 7839 "CLARK" 2
7934 7782 "MILLER" 3

Comment: I expect the output of mgr name too

Comment: Add `, prior ename` in first line.

Answer (score 0):

Add an alias in the FROM clause and use a nested correlated subquery in the SELECT clause.

```
SELECT  empno,mgr,ename,level, (select ename from emp where empno=e.mgr) mgrname
FROM emp e
START WITH ename = 'KING'
CONNECT BY  PRIOR empno = mgr;
```